Assigning a random value to a Spring property (Kafka topic) between tests
I'm writing a Spring Boot application with Kafka and want to achieve full test isolation by creating a new topic for my consumers and producers in each test, as Gary Russell explained here: How to clear topics in tests with Spring Kafka
I think I can achieve that by modifying a property with a topic name between tests, let's say it's ${kafka.topicName}.
How can I assign a new random value to a property via, I assume, @DynamicPropertySource or some other mechanism before every test?
Any other tips as to achieve the "new topic for each test" goal would be helpful as well.

Assuming you'd just use the AdminClient to create topics (i.e. ignoring Spring), you could :

make a topic per test method, rather than "random"

try using an AtomicInteger between tests that you'd String.format("test%d", num.incrementAndGet())

create a random UUID per test. The likelihood of collisions is small.

use Testcontainers to start/stop an ephemeral container between tests. The native-image Kafka container starts very fast and doesn't take much resources


